# Is there a pointer for each touch point in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch

I have been researching everywhere and can't find if there is a unique identifier for each touch point in ios.  I also would like to know how to access that in swift but can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: why do you need something like that?

Comment: Working on a multiple touch app that needs to track multiple touches.  An identifier from the system would be a better way to track the touch than an arbitrary touch identifier that I assigned. If there was a unique id it would make for quicker and easier data parsing.

Comment: the touch object does not change till it ends from the start. in touchesmoved event the same touch object we got in touches began is returned. each finger will have a unique touch object till its released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really for each point, but for each touch. To access them requires your own touch handling, for example in the UIView where the touches occur or its ViewController. This simply requires you to write your own methods for `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

When `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` are called by iOS, they report the touches in an `NSSet`. Each member of that set is a unique pointer to the touch data structure, and you should use them as the keys in an `NSMutableDictionary` if you want to filter touches over time.

Like that in `touchesBegan`, when you encounter a touch for the first time:

```
var pointDict: [String?: NSObject?] = [:]

...

func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

// Regular multitouch handling.
    for touch in touches.allObjects as UITouch {
// Create a new key from the UITouch pointer:
        let key = \(touch)
// Put the point into the dictionary as an NSValue
        pointDict.setValue(NSValue(CGPoint: touch.locationInView(myView)), forKey:key)
    }
}
```

Now in `touchesMoved` you need to check the pointer against the stored keys:

```
func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in touches.allObjects as UITouch {
// Create a new key from the UITouch pointer:
        let key = \(touch)

// See if the key has been used already:
        let oldPoint = pointDict[key]
        if oldPoint != nil {
    (do whatever is needed to continue the point sequence here)
        }
    }
}
```

If there is already an entry which uses the same touchID as its key, you get the stored object for the key back. If no previous touch used that ID, the dictionary will return nil when you ask it for the corresponding object.

Now you can assign your own pointers to those touch points, knowing that they all belong to the same touch event.

Comment: @Simon: I know, but when the documentation lists only the objC way, and you can mix Swift and objC, he needs to implement that part in objC.

Comment: There is a swifty way to do it tho: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:

Comment: Thank you so much for this input.  I am trying it out now.  It seems like this should work very well.  Thanks again.

Comment: I get an error that says "Type String does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'".  But I am still looking at everything else.  Should it be NSValue not string?