# Getting the pointer from a touch event

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uitouch

So I have asked a similar question before but this one is a little different.  Previous conversation: [Is there a pointer for each touch point in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746459/is-there-a-pointer-for-each-touch-point-in-ios/27768197#27768197)

From this I get the entire touch event information.  Which is really nice to have.  But the information comes out like this for a single touch event:

```
<UITouch: 0x7b657920> phase: Began tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x7b65e150; 
frame = (0 0; 768 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b65e590>; 
layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7b65b940>> view: <UIView: 0x7b660b90; 
frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b660640>> 
location in window: {252.00002, 562.00012} previous location in window: {252.00002, 562.00012} 
location in view: {252.00002, 562.00012} previous location in view: {252.00002, 562.00012}
```

I need to figure out a way to just get the information at the beginning.  The pointer right after the UITouch:  I would prefer not to have to transfer this to a different array of these pointers but if need be I will.  I know how to do that.  I was just wondering if anyone knew how to get that pointer out of there without having to do all the extra processing.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with 'at the beginning'? At the beginning of what? What do you mean with 'pointer'?

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? It looks like you have printed out some information about a `UITouch` object using the `debugDescription` or `description` property. This would indicate to me that you already *have* the pointer. What is the output that you are looking for and for which purpose do you intend to use that information? Maybe there's a different question that you're actually asking but don't know how?

Comment: The UITouch pointer object is the thing that I am trying to get out.  I apologize for not being clearer.  I am just trying to get 0x7b657920 out of the touch object.  I am going to use this as the key for a dictionary of touch objects.  But I don't know how to access this directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have that long list of pointers and information in string format, so to obtain just the "0x7b657920" you could just do something like:

```
var str = descriptionString //The info from the touch event
let rangeOfPointer = Range(start: advance(str.startIndex, 10),
                     end: advance(str.startIndex, 20))
let pointerStr = str.substringWithRange(rangeOfPointer)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This was exactly what I did but I did not edit the question.  Thank you